# Output R code in R console

Tags: r, text, vector

If I send this code:

```
c("apple", "pear", "pineapple", "melon", "grape")
```

This is the output in the R console:

```
[1] "apple"     "pear"      "pineapple" "melon"     "grape"
```

Is there a way of instead outputting R code in the R console instead? So this would be output in the R console:

```
  c("apple", "pear", "pineapple", "melon", "grape")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `dput`

```
v1 <- c("apple", "pear", "pineapple", "melon", "grape")
dput(v1)
#c("apple", "pear", "pineapple", "melon", "grape")
```

As @Richard Sciven mentioned, `deparse` could be one way to reuse it.

```
cat(paste0(deparse(v1), '\n'))
#c("apple", "pear", "pineapple", "melon", "grape")
```